# Error 53 makes my sister's iPhone 6 brick

Tags: iphone, ios, security

Little did I know, my sister had encountered an issue that Apple bricks her iPhone, after she repaired her iPhone 6 by a non-Apple technician.

Later, I hear reports that iOS 9.2 restore fails if it detects that a repair has been carried out by a non-Apple technician. I also know that this is a touch ID related problem.I have to advise her to ask Apple support team for help.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You don't solve it. You give the phone to Apple & they send it away. It can't be fixed in-store. Whether or not you can persuade them to give you a new phone is dependent on why it's Error 53'd & if it's under warranty.

Comment: I think you have a good chance in getting it solved in the Apple Store with the class action law suit Apple is risking concerning this problem.

Comment: Thank you. It's under warranty, and I will consult Apple Store staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the iPhone was serviced by a third-party, the phone is bricked. Apple will issue an out of warranty replacement, but it will be quite expensive. (It is an out of warranty replacement because the technician voided the warranty when he replaced internal components.)

Apple is not just doing this for fun. It keeps your biometric data secure. If someone at the mall, for example, replies your Touch ID sensor with another one, he can gain access to the iPhone and your information is not secure. While it may be frustrating, there is a good reason it happens.

Comment: You are right. I know Apple is not doing this for fun, it is because Error 53 is a security feature that’s being triggered by what the company sees as a legitimate concern. Given the number of complaints from customers, however, it seems that Apple may have strayed too far across the line and has started inconveniencing their legitimate users.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm not sure I would be willing to potentially sacrifice my privacy and security just to save some money by getting the iPhone serviced by a third-party. Privacy means a lot to me. It's a tough compromise for them to have to deal with.

Comment: Yeah, it is a tough compromise for them. The "Error 53" part, however, was meant to be shown at factories, not to consumers. So, Apple has released an iOS update to fix it.

Comment: It should also be noted that anyone who was charged for an out-of-warranty replacement from Apple should contact AppleCare for reimbursement.

Comment: Yep. You are considerate.  I'm very pleasant to talk with you..hahah  :)

Comment: You as well! It's refreshing to see someone who tries to understand their intentions first, rather than automatically start attacking them. @Mark

Comment: You are right. May I follow you in twitter?

Comment: OK. Thank you. I followed you just now. but I don't find the "space" between @ and C. My intuition tells me that it's you.  Am I wrong? :)

Comment: I had to use the space because Stack Exchange is trying to tag a user with that username. I think I see you. I'll follow back! @Mark

Comment: Great! I get it. @ComputerScienceStudent

Answer (score 0):

Error 53 can be corrected if it's a software issue. Apple documents this quite well and what to do online:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205628

  1. Update iTunes
  2. Force restart the device and attempt a restore of the device
  3. Have an Apple authorized service agent or Apple repair the hardware

It's likely someone tampered with the touch sensor if you have a hardware issue and Apple will let you know if it's covered under warranty when you seek service. I would make a backup before you try the restore just in case it works / erases your data.

Additionally, Apple's article now states that error 53 was intended for factory diagnostics and updating the device to iOS 9.2.1 or later will remedy this behavior.

You don't get touch ID back, but the device works just as it did after the repair/damage and before you tried to restore the phone. No data loss is enforced by this update.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a Home Button issue after a display change so I was curious about if my phone would be bricked with the next update. According to my research, Apple is no longer bricking phones (there was a lawsuit on this issue) after a home button change. The only thing that fails to work is the touch ID sensor. The touch ID sensor is always paired to the original phone.