# Digitizer assembly replacement and Error 53

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

As you probably know, Error 53 is Apple intentionally bricking your iDevice due to a 3rd-party repairing it, or specifically changing the TouchID sensor.

If I merely change the screen (LCD, digitizer, and glass) and detach the TouchID sensor from the old screen and reattach the same sensor to the new screen, could this potentially cause Error 53?

Comment: It seems the [official stance to press](http://techcrunch.com/2016/02/18/apple-apologizes-and-updates-ios-to-restore-iphones-disabled-by-error-53/) is that this was a factory check and only affects iTunes restores with iOS 9.2 and lower. You can get iTunes to install iOS 9.2.1 and not have any "intentional bricking" as you initially say.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has released a fixed version of iOS 9.2 (specifically 9.2.1 and later) which will restore the device to operation.

It doesn't fix the touch sensor - but you can use the device.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205628

Also see:

[Error 53 makes my sister's iPhone 6 brick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227731/error-53-makes-my-sisters-iphone-6-brick)

So - if you disturb/tamper with the touch sensor - you won't brick the device when updating from iTunes (as opposed to an OTA update which doesn't throw error 53 for iOS 9.2 and lower), but the sensor won't work going forward.

Answer (score 0):

If *anything* is done to the Touch ID sensor, welcome to Error 53. Take your iPhone to the Genius Bar for repair. It's not cheap, but it's cheaper than buying a new iPhone.